# Image in HTML not displayed ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: html

I am trying to display an image using plain HTML and the code is given below.  There are several posts in SO similar to this but the issue is not resolved

```
<html>
<body>
<IMG SRC=”Test.jpg” ALIGN=”left” alt="File not exist" />
</body>
</html>
```

The above code produced the error 'net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND' and I use Windows 10

1. Both the files are placed under the same folder F:\
2. I am able to browse the jpg file from browser by typing F:/Test.jpg
3. I tried from Edge and Chrome browsers and both produced the same error
4. I cleared the cache / used incognito window but nothing worked

Any suggestion is highly appreciated

**EDIT**

Both the files are in the same folder.  One thing what I noticed is few junk characters were prepended and appended to the image file name.  I am not sure whether this is the reason

Comment: img src align  should all be lowercase

Comment: also could you put a screenshot of your folder structure?

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to make your alt text more descriptive, for screen readers and search engines

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="Test.jpg" align="left" alt="File not exist" />
</body>
</html> <!---now this image will run properly..-->
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low quality answers.

Comment: the problem is depending on your letters... check your code, some letters of code is written in capital letters .. i re-wrote thats only....